# create a new desktop background from default background

Tags: desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 14.4.3 and really like the default cyan background.

I want it to not change with time. However, I cannot find the file in `/usr/share/backgrounds`. I was hoping to construct an image background and install that. Does anyone have a solution for this?

(edited to add the following)

Here is a shot of the one I want

[image]

Comment: Findo out the image's location with: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri`. See the dupe.